# How can I change layout of apple ColorPicker from Circle to Square in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, color-picker

The default button style of ColorPicker is a circle as bellow.

[image]

I want to change the style of the circle button to Rectangle. But seems no API can change it style. So I put a Rectangle over it , and set it allowsHitTesting to false to transport click event to ColorPicker.

[image]

```
struct ColorPickerView: View {
    @State private var colorValue = Color.orange
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            ColorPicker("", selection: $colorValue)
                .labelsHidden()
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
    }
}
```

But the ColorPicker did not present after click.

I put a circle bellow the Rectangle to test whether allowsHitTesting is useful. It can work properly responding to tap gesture to print "Circle tapped!".

```
struct ColorPickerView: View {
    @State private var colorValue = Color.orange
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            ColorPicker("", selection: $colorValue)
                .labelsHidden()
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Circle tapped!")
                }
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Why the ColorPicker can not responding to tap gesture? Or Is there a way to customize the ColorPicker button？

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply use `opacity`, and send the **ColorPicker** to `overlay`, like in the code:

---

### [image]

```
struct SquareColorPickerView: View {
    
    @Binding var colorValue: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        
        colorValue
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5)))
            .padding(10)
            .background(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red,.yellow,.green,.blue,.purple,.pink]), center:.center).cornerRadius(20.0))
            .overlay(ColorPicker("", selection: $colorValue).labelsHidden().opacity(0.015))
            .shadow(radius: 5.0)

    }
}
```

---

***Use case:***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var colorValue = Color.orange
    
    var body: some View {

        SquareColorPickerView(colorValue: $colorValue)

    }
}
```

Comment: How long have you used swiftui and how can I reach your level?

Comment: There are much better than me here, I am just new here. but thanks. :)

Comment: *macOS 12*: it works, but `opacity` cannot be lower than `0.075` or it won't receive clicks. But that's close to invisible. The other quirk is that the click area stays the same size as `ColorPicker`'s original color well, i.e. a little smaller than the rounded square. I'm still looking for a better solution (with the native interface).

Answer (score 0):

Refined @ios coder's answer to have adjustable size. A `Bool` to toggle Square/Circle view would be a nice touch. *Credit: ios coder.*

```swift
struct EyedropperColorPicker: View {
    @Binding var colorValue: Color
    var size: CGFloat = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        colorValue
            .frame(width: size, height: size, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(size * 0.25) // adjust corner radius proportional to size
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: size * 0.25)
                .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: size * 0.125))) // adjust border width proportional to size
            .padding(size * 0.25) // adjust padding proportional to size
            .background(
                AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red,.yellow,.green,.blue,.purple,.pink]), center: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(size * 0.5) // adjust corner radius proportional to size
            )
            .overlay(ColorPicker("", selection: $colorValue).labelsHidden().opacity(0.015))
            .shadow(radius: size * 0.125) // adjust shadow radius proportional to size
    }
}
```