# SwiftUI ColorPicker on macOS looks weird

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, color-picker, mac-catalyst

My ColorPicker looks fine on iPad/iPhone, with colored circles, but on macOS, the color is a rectangle that almost fills the screen width, but isn't even consistent.  Using Xcode 12.4, Swift 5, mac catalyst, iOS target is 14.0.  Here is the image:
[image: ColorPicker on macOS]

and the code is just standard SwiftUI like this:

```
Section(header: Text("Region")) {
                        ColorPicker("Active region color", selection: Binding(
                                        get: { activeColor },
                                        set: { newValue in
                                            activeColorName = newValue.toString
                                            activeColor = newValue
                                        }))

                    }
```

Any way to make this look as pretty as the ColorPicker appearance on iOS devices?  At least eliminate the ragged left margin?  Almost makes me miss AutoLayout.

EDIT:

I ended up doing something like this:

```
Section(header: Text("Region")) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Active region color")
                            Spacer()
                            ColorPicker("", selection: Binding(
                                            get: { activeColor },
                                            set: { newValue in
                                                activeColorName = newValue.toString
                                                activeColor = newValue
                                            }))
                                .frame(maxWidth: 500)
                        }
                    }
```

But I am surprised that this is necessary, and certainly this isn't as pretty as what you see running on an iDevice.

Comment: In my Catalyst project, I used `frame(maxWidth: )` to give them a uniform size.

Comment: 3 years later, the issue persists.

Comment: 4 years later, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and here is my workaround.

Inspired by this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67145239/16083169)

bgColor is the background color of your original view that this color picker will be placed on. In my case bgcolor is -> bgColor: Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)

```
    struct CircleColorPickerView: View {
    
    var title : String
    @Binding var colorValue: Color
    var bgColor : Color
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let size : CGFloat = 25
        
        colorValue
            .frame(width: size, height: size, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(size)
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(bgColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2)))
            .padding(4)
            .background(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red,.yellow,.green,.blue,.purple,.pink]), center:.center).cornerRadius(size))
            .overlay(ColorPicker(title, selection: $colorValue, supportsOpacity: false).labelsHidden().opacity(0.015))
            //.shadow(radius: 5.0)

    }
}
```

This works fine on both iOS and macOS. However, I want to keep original look and feel of ColorPicker in iOS so I use if condition to use this workaround when running on macOS only.

Hope this help.