# opening ColorPicker by tapping another view (object), not the small circle

Tags: swift, swiftui, color-picker

Is there a way of tapping another view/object and open the picker (with a onTapGesture for instance? Apparently the only way is tapping on the small circle :|

I would like to tap the [violet object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVUa4.png) and have the picker open.

I appreciate any help, thanks !

```
VStack {
    ColorPicker("Color picker :", selection: $selectedColor, supportsOpacity: false)
        .padding()
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(selectedColor)
        .onTapGesture {
            // open picker :)
        }
}
```

Comment: I answered same question in the past in this link! https://stackoverflow.com/a/67145239/14998134

Comment: thanks @swiftPunk for your answer.
it's not exactly the way i was interest to implement,  because i would like to hide le little color circle and click another element to open the picker. but it was worth to learn something else ... thanks!

Comment: I believe you could not use it, because it is exactly what you are searching.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you have to create your own instance of UIColorPickerViewController and then activate it with SwiftUI.

I tried a few things using only SwiftUI and at least I couldn't do it

Comment: Thanks @Zapata for your answer.

That was my fear, the need to implement UIKit stuff on a shiny SwiftUI code. Inevitable ...